# Finding the first day of this week in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

How might I select the first day of this week in Informix SQL?

Comment: Which day is first day, according to your location?

Comment: What are columns in the table? Is the day of the week in date format or is it in number format is the date just in one column?

Answer (score 2):

Informix takes Sunday as the first day of the week (number 0). If you want to find the most recent Sunday, then this would do it:

```
SELECT TODAY - (WEEKDAY(TODAY)) UNITS DAY
FROM   systables
WHERE  tabid=1;
```

The `FROM` clause is required, and you could put another table there depending on what else you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791299) by [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot), if you want the first day of the week to be the day with code N, then the expression should be:

```
date_col - MOD(7 + WEEKDAY(date_col) - N, 7)
```

Clearly, when N is 0, the MOD expression is equivalent to `WEEKDAY(date_col)` and the result is therefore the same as given by trincot.

For example, for Monday (day 1) as the first day of the week, for the dates in November 2015 (where 2015-11-01 was a Sunday), I created a table Date_List with a single column `d` of type `DATE` and inserted a record for each in November 2015.

```
SELECT d AS Date, WEEKDAY(d) AS W1,
       d - WEEKDAY(d) AS Sunday,
       MOD(7 + WEEKDAY(d) - 1, 7) AS W2,
       d - MOD(7 + WEEKDAY(d) - 1, 7) AS Mondat
  FROM date_list
 ORDER BY d;
```

#### Results

The column labelled 'Sunday' shows the date of the Sunday on or before the date in the first column; the column labelled 'Monday' shows the date of the Monday on or before the date in the first column.

```
Date        W1   Sunday      W2   Monday
2015-11-01   0   2015-11-01   6   2015-10-26
2015-11-02   1   2015-11-01   0   2015-11-02
2015-11-03   2   2015-11-01   1   2015-11-02
2015-11-04   3   2015-11-01   2   2015-11-02
2015-11-05   4   2015-11-01   3   2015-11-02
2015-11-06   5   2015-11-01   4   2015-11-02
2015-11-07   6   2015-11-01   5   2015-11-02
2015-11-08   0   2015-11-08   6   2015-11-02
2015-11-09   1   2015-11-08   0   2015-11-09
2015-11-10   2   2015-11-08   1   2015-11-09
2015-11-11   3   2015-11-08   2   2015-11-09
2015-11-12   4   2015-11-08   3   2015-11-09
2015-11-13   5   2015-11-08   4   2015-11-09
2015-11-14   6   2015-11-08   5   2015-11-09
2015-11-15   0   2015-11-15   6   2015-11-09
2015-11-16   1   2015-11-15   0   2015-11-16
2015-11-17   2   2015-11-15   1   2015-11-16
2015-11-18   3   2015-11-15   2   2015-11-16
2015-11-19   4   2015-11-15   3   2015-11-16
2015-11-20   5   2015-11-15   4   2015-11-16
2015-11-21   6   2015-11-15   5   2015-11-16
2015-11-22   0   2015-11-22   6   2015-11-16
2015-11-23   1   2015-11-22   0   2015-11-23
2015-11-24   2   2015-11-22   1   2015-11-23
2015-11-25   3   2015-11-22   2   2015-11-23
2015-11-26   4   2015-11-22   3   2015-11-23
2015-11-27   5   2015-11-22   4   2015-11-23
2015-11-28   6   2015-11-22   5   2015-11-23
2015-11-29   0   2015-11-29   6   2015-11-23
2015-11-30   1   2015-11-29   0   2015-11-30
```

#### Calendars for October and November 2015

```
    October 2015
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31

   November 2015
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30
```

#### Stored procedures

It would be possible, and trivial to write stored procedures to do these calculations.

```
CREATE FUNCTION nday_on_or_before(ref_date DATE, nday INTEGER) RETURNING DATE;
    RETURN ref_date - MOD(7 + WEEKDAY(ref_date) - nday, 7);
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION sunday_on_or_before(ref_date DATE) RETURNING DATE;
    RETURN nday_on_or_before(ref_date, 0);
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION monday_on_or_before(ref_date DATE) RETURNING DATE;
    RETURN nday_on_or_before(ref_date, 1);
END FUNCTION;
```

Etc.

If you want the Monday strictly before the reference date, then you can use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nday_before(ref_date DATE, nday INT) RETURNING DATE;
    RETURN nday_on_or_before(ref_date - 1, nday);
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION sunday_before(ref_date DATE) RETURNING DATE;
    RETURN nday_on_or_before(ref_date - 1, 0);
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION monday_before(ref_date DATE) RETURNING DATE;
    RETURN nday_on_or_before(ref_date - 1, 1);
END FUNCTION;
```

Etc.  Note that the `nday_*` functions do not validate that the `nday` parameter is in the range 0..6; that can be done by applying the MOD function more often:

```
 MOD(MOD(nday, 7) + 7, 7)
```

That yields a value in the range 0..6 regardless of whether the input value of `nday` is positive or negative, because the inner MOD returns a value in the range -6..+6, and the outer converts that to 0..6.  Alternatively, the functions could throw an exception when the `nday` value is out of range.